# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function with activeadmin rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to integrate a simple modal in activeadmin.

My Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'popper_js'
gem 'bootstrap'
```

My application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

My action_item in:

```
action_item :query, only: :view_form do
  link_to 'New Query', admin_participants_form_queries_path(:id => participant.id, :survey_type => type, :form_name => form_name),  {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'}
end
```

My admin-controller-method:

```
def admin_queries
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

my js file:

```
$("#modal-window").find(".modal-content").html("<%= j (render 'queries_modal') %>");
$("#modal-window").modal('show');
```

Any help with the above issue will be hugely appretiated. thank you in advance

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your jquery is not being recognized:
Try adding this to your `config/webpack/environment.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery/src/jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
    })
)
```